# Activating QPainter upon hover event

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

Here is some code that illustrates my problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class CustomButton(QtGui.QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, *__args):
        super().__init__(*__args)
        self.setFixedSize(190, 50)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(136, 212, 78))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 48))

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverMove:
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.begin(self)
            painter.drawRect(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 48))
            painter.end()
            return True
        return False

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(window)

button = CustomButton()
layout.addWidget(button, 0, 0)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The goal is to make a button using `QPainter` that can be modified when the `HoverMove` event is detected. However, I get the following errors upon hovering:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

From what I've understood from the docs ([here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpainter.html#details)) I can use `.begin()` to activate the `QPainter`; however as the error message shows this isn't the case and the second rectangle does not get drawn. How should I use `QPainter` to achieve the desired output ?

Comment: As the docs say: "**Warning**: When the paintdevice is a widget, QPainter can only be used inside a paintEvent() function or in a function called by paintEvent(); that is unless the Qt.WA_PaintOutsidePaintEvent widget attribute is set. On Mac OS X and Windows, you can only paint in a paintEvent() function regardless of this attribute's setting."

Comment: Oops, my bad then, missed the most important part :/. If it can only be used in `paintEvent()` is it possible to call this method from the event handler with arguments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to detect the hover inside `paintEvent` and act accordingly:

```
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        option = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()
        option.initFrom(self)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            # do hover stuff ...
        else:
            # do normal stuff ...
```

[QStyleOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleoption.html) and its subclasses contain all the information that [QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/porting4.html#qstyle) functions need to draw a graphical element. The [QPaintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpaintevent.html) only contains information about what area needs to be updated.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to solve the problem. However it might be a good idea to precise that `painter.end()` is required at the end of the function or the program will crash. Before I accept, would you mind explaining the use of `QStyleOptionButton` over checking the type of the event ?

Comment: I've added a little further explanation, but all the details are available in the Qt docs. It is not necessary to explicitly call `end()`, because it's automatically invoked by the destructor. Checking the type of the event would be pointless, since it cannot be anything other than a `QPaintEvent`.

Comment: calling `option.initFrom(self)` simply adds to `option.state` the result of `self.underMouse()`

Comment: @MarcheRemi That's not the point of doing things that way. There's much more to drawing a custom widget than getting the mouse-over state. The style options provide a very efficient way to obtain all the relevant information in a single step.

Comment: @ekhumoro, the question is specifically about hovering.

Comment: @MarcheRemi "The goal is to make a button using QPainter that can be modified when the HoverMove event is detected".

Answer (score 0):

[@ekhumoro's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146177/9329985) can be rewritten more simply with `QWidget::underMouse()`. [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#underMouse)

```
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if underMouse():
            # do hover stuff ...
        else:
            # do normal stuff ...
```